# Sort data from txt file into columns using python

Tags: python, dataframe, text, keyword

I am using Python
I have one txt file containing data organised like this:

```
acertainfilepathendingwith.txt T+anumber Keywordcategory notimportantnumber anothernotimportantnumber asentencewithrelevantinformation
```

Example:

```
C:\Test.txt T5 Plane 2848 3102 An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
```

I would like to create a dataframe looking like this:

```
acertainfilepathendingwith.txt|Keywordcategory|asentencewithrelevantinformation
```

So for my example:

```
C:\Test.txt|Plane|An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
```

The issue is that I can't differentiate every potential column because there is only one space between them and in the "asentencewithrelevantinformation" there are also spaces.

So I thought about entering all keywords from Keywordcategory so this part is doable. But how do I deal with the "asentencewithrelevantinformation"?

Thank you

Comment: If you can identify everything *but* the sentence, just take everything after the stuff you can identify *as* the sentence.

Comment: I see what you mean, i will try that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split()      
        out = a[0]+'|'+a[2]+'|'                
        for x in a:
            if a.index(x) > 4:
                out += x+' '
        print(out)
        a.clear()
```

Edit:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n':
            pass
        else:
            a = line.split()      
            out = a[0]+'|'+a[2]+'|'                
            for x in a:
                if a.index(x) > 4:
                    out += x+' '
            print(out)
            a.clear()
```

Comment: Your code works well. I had an index error while running it but it's because I have an empty line between each relevant line. I'm trying to fix it right now.

Comment: I can confirm the edit version worked and avoided empty lines. Thank you for your help!